# How can I get my AWS Lambda to access gems stored in vendor/bundle?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, bundler

I'm writing a Lambda function in Ruby which will eventually send me some notifications in Slack via Webhook.  So what I have for my `lambda_function` file is

```
require 'json'
require 'webhook'

def lambda_handler(event:, context:)
    # TODO implement
    { statusCode: 200, body: JSON.generate('Hello from Lambda!') }
    Webhook.post('https://mywebhookurl', {message: 'test'})
end
```

And the directory structure in my inline code editor looks like this:

```
Gemfile
Gemfile.lock
lambda_function.rb
vendor/
  bundle/
    ruby
      2.3.0
        gems/webhook
```

also under the `2.3.0` bath are several other folders including `build_info`,  `cache`, `doc` etc.  In order to get this code onto AWS Lambda, I'm running

`zip -r myLambda.zip *` to get everything into a zip file and uploaded to Lambda.

However, when I finally go to run a basic test on the lambda, I get the following error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "cannot load such file -- webhook",
  "errorType": "Init<LoadError>",
  "stackTrace": [
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'",
    "/var/task/lambda_function.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'"
  ]
}
```

There shouldn't be any more to this as the [following tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/ruby-package.html#ruby-package-dependencies) shows exactly how to set up what I have, but doesn't work.  Does anyone have success pulling gems from their gemfile in AWS Lambda?

Comment: well you bundled under 2.3.0 and are running under 2.5.0 this could be a good place to start

Answer (score 19):

I ran into this same problem when building AWS Lambda Layers w/ Ruby. A quick and easy way to get this to work is to add all of the gem paths to Ruby's $LOAD_PATH in your AWS Lambda. IE:

```
load_paths = Dir["/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/**/lib"]
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(*load_paths)

require 'webhook'
```

Replace `"/opt/ruby/gems/2.5.0/**/lib"` with `"./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/**/lib"` in your case.

When you do `require 'webhook'` it's going to go and look through all of the paths and come across `"./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/webhook-1.0.0/lib/webhook.rb"` and add it into your AWS Lambda. `require` doesn't require a file extension.

When we run rails through bundler it does a bunch of 'magic' for us including making sure that our $LOAD_PATH is pointing at the gems. Since AWS Lambdas don't use bundler, we need to do some of this 'magic' ourselves.

Comment: I ran into a similar issue when trying to use a gem from GitHub (`master` branch). It seems that the path to my gem was not the same one, it was under: `./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bundler/gems/`. That means that I had to tweak those two lines so that it looks like this: `load_paths = Dir["./vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bundler/gems/**/lib"]`. I don't know if it makes a difference: I was using `bundler` version 2.0.1.

Comment: I needed this *AND* the `2.3` -> `2.5` answer.

Comment: For those looking for a simple example, you can find one here: https://github.com/ryanjones/ruby_lambda_layers

Answer (score 14):

You need to make sure the version of Ruby you used locally to bundle matches the version used by Lambda.

Your zip appears to have the gems installed in 2.3.0 but your stack trace lists 2.5.0. This mismatch means lambda runner can’t find your gems.

Answer (score 5):

I think you should not change the GEM_PATH or having to set `$LOAD_PATH` in every lambda functions.
The "best" way is to do this little hack when you create the layer archive:

```
bundle install --path vendor/bundle
cd vendor/bundle
mkdir ruby/gems
mv ruby/2.5.0 ruby/gems/
zip -r layer.zip ruby/gems/2.5.0/
```