# AWS Lambda: Ruby function failing to load gem

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, rubygems, aws-lambda

I have a Ruby Lambda function which depends on an external (ie non-AWS) RubyGem.  I have a `Gemfile`, a `Gemfile.lock` and a `vendor/bundle` directory. Everything looks fine from a local perspective.

I've tried using `bundle install --path vendor/bundle` and `bundle install --deployment` to install the gems, and am specifically including the `vendor` directory when zipping up the files: `zip -r function.zip myfunction.rb vendor`

Despite this, when I test the function in the Lambda console, it's failing with errors complaining about not being able to find the libraries, e.g.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "cannot load such file -- mysql2",
  "errorType": "Init<LoadError>",
  "stackTrace": [
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'",
    "/var/task/hello_ruby_record.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'",
    "/var/lang/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'"
  ]
}
```

Presumably I'm doing something really obviously wrong in bundling up the gems before uploading the function; but I can't figure out what. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53634260/how-can-i-get-my-aws-lambda-to-access-gems-stored-in-vendor-bundle#comment94129753_53634260 Could it be the same issue here? Where you local version is not `2.5` and thus is being bundled under a different ruby version

Comment: Doesn't look like gems are loaded to the $LOAD_PATH - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53698808/677322

Comment: *pauses from banging head against desk* yes, the answer was right there in front of me - thanks to both for point it out. It was a bundling problem. My local Ruby version was ahead of Lambda - explicitly setting the Ruby version with RVM fixes the problem *resumes banging head against desk*

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue. The underlying reason is different ruby versions being used in local and Lambda function. Currently AWS Lambda is using Ruby 2.5 and your gems are located at '/vendor/bundle/ruby/'. Thus your lambda function is unable to locate the gem libraries uploaded by you. To override the gem path with your Ruby version, add the below mentioned code at the top of your file containing the handler function:

```
  my_gem_path = Dir["./vendor/bundle/ruby/<your-ruby-version>/gems/**/lib"]
  $LOAD_PATH.unshift(*my_gem_path)
```

Or, just try upgrading and matching your local Ruby version with the exact version used by Lambda function viz 2.5 currently.

Comment: Even minor versions will mess it. (I had 2.5.1)

Comment: @TimD can you mark this answer as accepted?

Answer (score 5):

Please do make sure your bundle config is exactly this:

```
BUNDLE_PATH: "vendor/bundle"
```

If you just follow what [the official document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/ruby-package.html) says:

To update a Ruby function with dependencies

1. Install libraries in the vendor directory using the bundle command.

```
bundle config set --local path 'vendor/bundle' \ 
bundle install
```

......

You will get a redundant trailing space, which mess things up:

```
BUNDLE_PATH: "vendor/bundle " <-- a trailing space here
```

I am using `ruby 2.7.3p183 (2021-04-05 revision 6847ee089d) [x86_64-darwin19]` and it works without problem.

Comment: Crazy but it's true - the `bundle config` put in a trailing space and caused problems. Beware!